# How to duplicate a project target in XCode4

Tags: iphone, xcode, project

I want to create a target with different bundle id for test environment. I tried using the "Duplicate" function to clone a target and change the bundle id and found that the orignal one was changed too.  Thanks for any tips!

================== Update =====================

Solve the link error after duplicates the target, it is a xcode bug. The quote character " is changed to \" in search paths(Building setting of the target).

see detail: http://flakasoft.com/developer-tips/xcode-4-bug-duplicating-a-target-results-in-link-error-due-to-missing-paths/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double check you have the new duplicate target selected when you modify the *Bundle Identifier* setting on the Info Tab. I just tried this and it worked fine.

So the bundle identifier is on the info tab, which is actually just a view of the info.pList associated with the target.

To change the info.pList on that target, you will need to make a copy of the pList file (newtarget-info.pList), go into the *Build Settings* tab for the target, scroll down to the *Packaging* segment and modify the *Info.pList File* setting to point to your new file.

Then when you click on the info tab you will get the settings from your newtarget-info.pList file.

Comment: I did change bundle identity on the new duplicated target. Just seems it was using the same XXX-Info.plist file as the orignal one. Can't figure out why. Did you use this functionality in XCode4?

Comment: Oh! I see what you have done. There is a separate setting for the pList file. (updating answer)

Answer (score 4):

Figure it out.In XCode4, after duplicate the target, the info.plist file need to be duplicated too.
1. Copy the orignal info.plist file, usually "{APP Name}-Info.plist"
2. Change the setting: "Build Settings"->"Info.plist Files"