# Reuse Xcode project for new app

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store, app-store-connect

Similar questions have been asked before, but I can't find the specific details I'm looking for. I have an Xcode project which has been completed and submitted and is on the App Store. I want to make a similar app for release in a different country. To avoid complications, I want to use a fresh project in which to make the changes. I intend to make a copy of the original project, tweak it, and then release it (this is not about language so localization is not the answer).

Because Xcode is doing so much complicated stuff under the hood, and because I'm unsure of exactly which details are being validated when submitting to the App Store, I don't know which details I need to change to ensure two separate projects on my Mac and two separate apps in iTunes Connect.

Obviously I will need new provisioning profiles for the new project. What else do I need to change once I've duplicated my project? The bundle identifier maybe? Anything else? Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a Xcode expert but I'm sure that the bundle identifier in your app's plist must be different otherwise the two different apps can't be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that must change between projects is the application ID (or bundle identifier, as you called it).

And yes, when you change the application ID, you do need to create new provisioning profiles to go with it.

If you're feeling really ambitious, you can use the exact *same* project as your original one and merely create a new target (and application).  That way any code changes you make to one can be picked up by the other and the differences would be the ID and maybe the localizations/resources used in each app.  [Here is a related question that talks about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516959/how-to-duplicate-a-project-target-in-xcode4).